# Haulting link href with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following link element:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="check_show('http://www.test.com')">Test</a>

<script>
function check_show(link){
    if($('#testelement).css('display') == 'block'){
        window.location.href = link;
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem with this is if I was to click to open in a new window (or ctrl-click), it will open a new windows for 'javascript:;'. So, I need to ad the link in the the href. This is fine, but I would like to still check #testelement is visible first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript is being ran, followed by the browser redirecting to the `href`. You need to prevent the browser from following this link. You can do this by adding `return false;` after your function call in your `onclick`.

```
<a href="LINKHERE" onclick="check_show('http://www.test.com'); return false;">Test</a>
```

Comment: One should probably place the `return false;` in `check_show()`.

Comment: @kevin628 In that case the `onclick` attribute would also need to be `onclick="return check_show('http://www.test.com');`. Of course, ideally since jQuery is already being used, these event handlers would be bound using that rather than inline attributes on elements.

Comment: @Curt That works for right click and open in a new window. But it's doesn't for ctrl-click actions in firefox.